# EntityFramework: possible many-2-many bug in EF 5.0?

Tags: entity-framework

I've a simple DbContext model with two entities Product and Order, and a single many-2-many association between them. I'm trying to explicitly load a specific associated order for a product instance. Therefore, I started with explicitly loading *all* orders for the product instance:

```
context.Entry(product).Collection(x=>x.Orders).Load();
```

product.Orders now contains all associated orders. So far so good. Now I want to make a more specific query by using the '.Query()' method like this:

```
context.Entry(product).Collection(x=>x.Orders).Query().Load();
```

Surprisingly, product.Orders is now empty!

According to the documentation, the Query() method should return 'the query that would be used to load this collection from the database.' Executing the ObjectQuery manually does give the expected result.

Am I doing something wrong, or is this a bug in EF?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Kind regards,
Merijn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference is that the second statement (with `Query().Load()`) only loads the orders into the context, *not in the collection*. <s>It's just a query that runs, it is not aware of any collection it should populate.</s>

You can verify that by listing `context.Orders.Local`. After the `Query().Load()` it will contain the orders belonging to `product`.

If `product.Orders` would be allowed to lazy load afterwards you would see the same query being executed, but now to populate the collection.

**Edit**
After clearing my head and keeping apart many-to-many, one-to-many, lazy/non-lazy I could fully reproduce your issue. A m:m navigation property is *not* loaded by `.Query().Load()`, whereas a 1:n navigation property is. The `Local` collection is loaded in both cases, though.

So, good catch!

Comment: Hi,Thanks for your reply. Two question: First question: is this in contrast to what Julia and Rowan write on page 41, section "Explicit loading a subset of the contents of a navigation property" in their book "Programming Entity Framework DbContext"? Second question: if I call the load method as you suggested, then indeed the orders are loaded in the context. But how to get them also in the collection Product.Orders. I tried to call DetectChanges() with no effect. Is it because product-order is an m2m relation?

Comment: The confusing part here is that a lazy loading collection will always be reloaded with all objects when it is addressed, or fail with a "context disposed" exception when accessing it after context disposal. So this only makes sense with non-lazy collections (and I tested with lazy ones). So, yes, you're right, `product.Orders` should contain the orders. I'll see if I will modify my answer or just remove it in due time.

Comment: Thanks again for helping me. But what about my second question? The thing is, I want to remove an m2m relation between a product and an order. I can load all m2m relations for the product by calling product.Orders.Load() but that seems not very efficient to me. I prefer to do it without a load at all (if EF would allow me to attach an order to  product.Orders), but otherwise I want to load just the one m2m association given the keys of the product and order. I'm getting a feeling that this is not possible. Am I right, or how could I do it?

Comment: Yes, you're right that because of this bug (or feature?) you have to load the _whole_ orders collection if you want to change anything in product-order associations. Or you must pull the association table into your class model, which will enable you to e.g. delete associations by order id and product id. Maybe a comfort: I often see hidden association tables sooner or later end up in the class model because of emerging requirements to store details about the association (like the date when it was established, a sequence number, etc.).

Comment: If I understand you correctly, this means dropping m2m in my model and use link tables everywhere. Is that right? What about this attach method I mentioned. Would it have a change as a feature for Vnext?

Comment: Well, everywhere... here it's about the ProductOrder (or similar) table and the m:m Products-Orders which would become Product-ProductOrder-Order (a regular association class with two n:1 associations). Sorry, I don't know about Vnext.